# Sub not found in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I m trying to create a button and fill the value for column on.5 based on the value in column no.4.
here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 3 To 1000

    If Cells(x, 4).Value = "Regular" Then
    Cells(x, 5).Value = Today()
    
    ElseIf Cells(x, 4).Value = "Temporary" And Cells(x, 5).Value = "" Then
    Cells(x, 5).Value = "To be assigned"
    
    Else
    Cells(x, 5).Value = ""
    
    End If

End Sub
```

This gives me the errors that sub or function is not defined.

I am new to VBA and trying to solve this, but could not do it.

Thanks.

Comment: And it is `Now()`

Answer (score -1):

VBA is ignoring the `End Sub`, because you haven't finished closing all of the clauses before it:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 3 To 1000
        If Cells(x, 4).Value = "Regular" Then
            Cells(x, 5).Value = Today() 'This should be Now()
        ElseIf Cells(x, 4).Value = "Temporary" And Cells(x, 5).Value = "" Then
            Cells(x, 5).Value = "To be assigned"
        Else
            Cells(x, 5).Value = ""
        End If
    'You are missing a "Next x" here
End Sub
```

Since the Sub is not complete, it does not count it as valid, so it cannot find it at compile time.

Comment: `TODAY()` is Excel, `Date` is VBA.

Comment: The Sub is complete. The error message is just saying that `Today` is not a defined sub. It has nothing to do with _Since the Sub is not complete, it does not count it as valid, so it cannot find it at compile time._ As soon as that error is fixed the compiler will run into _Next without For_ error. The error message in case of a missing `End Sub` would just be that a `End Sub` is missing.